# Как привязать функцию в MDCardSwipe?

Tags: python, kivy

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии первый слой MDCardSwipe (MDCardFrontBox) происходил переход на другой экран, а при нажатии на второй слой (MDCardLayerBox), он удалялся. Второе у меня получилось сделать, а вот первое никак не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
<CheckMark>:
_no_ripple_effect: True
IconLeftWidget:
    icon: root.left_icon


<ItemCardSwipe>:
size_hint_y: None
height: content.height

MDCardSwipeLayerBox:
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'trash-can'
        pos_hint: {'center_y'
        on_release: app.back()

MDCardSwipeFrontBox:
    CheckMark:
        id: content
        text: root.text
        left_icon: 'star'
        _no_ripple_effect: True
        on_release: lambda x: app.back()
```

Это сам MDCardSwipe.

Answer (score 0):

Я пытался добавить функцию в kv-файл, но почему-то так она не работает, поэтому я добавил её из кода .py

```
# присвоение функции для MDCardSwipeFrontBox, on_release - перемещение на избранный конвертер
    self.ids.content.on_release = lambda x='В избранный конвертер': self.move_to_window(x)
```